# How to refrain button input until after an animation has finished playing in unity 5?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animator

I am new to Unity and a beginner programmer. I experimented with Unity's GUI (canvas, button, label, etc...).

For the button, I made a class ButtonClickScript, so that when i tapped on the button, the variable waterBucketAmnt would increase until it reached 3. I then decided to take my experiment a little farther, so I created a very simple animation of a guy dumping a bucket of water. I wanted to restrict the amount of times the guy could dump the water using the waterBucketAmnt.

I can tap the GUI button 3 times and everything works fine. int waterBucketAmnt = 3. I then start the game and press the configured "Fire3" action on the keyboard and it does exactly as expected. The problem is that I can tap the "Fire3" action consecutively in less than a second, therefore, waterBucketAmnt = 0 and the animation plays only once. How can I delay input until the animation is completed?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class waterBucketAction : MonoBehavior {

Animator waterAnim;
// a simple player controller using unity's RigidBody2D feature. I added PlayerControllerScript so that I could make sure the player had to remain on the ground in order to dump the bucket of water. checkGround is so that I could inherit the grounded gameObject I created. 

PlayerControllerScript checkGround;
public ButtonClickScript checkWaterAmnt;

void Start () {
    checkGround = FindObjectOfType <playerControllerScript> ();
    waterAnim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
}

void FixedUpdate() {
    waterAnim.SetBool ("isPlaying", false);

    if (checkWaterAmnt.waterBucketAmnt > 0 && !waterAnim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("waterBucketAnimation")) {

        if (checkGround.grounded == true && Input.GetButtonDown ("Fire3")) {
            waterAnim.SetBool("isPlaying", true);

            //I need to wait for the animation to complete or delay the input. I searched multiple places and the best answer I could find was Animation.IsAnimating, but that seems to be deprecated? The API says that Animator replaced Animation, but I couldn't find an equivalent method.
            if(waterAnim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("waterBucketAnimation"))
                checkWaterAmnt.waterBucketAmnt -=1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that you `ButtonClickScript` looks like this:

```
public class ButtonClickScript : MonoBehavior, IPointerClickHandler
{
    public int waterBucketAmnt;

    void OnPointerClick() 
    {
        if (waterBucketAmnt < 3)
            waterBucketAmnt++;
    }
}
```

So what you need to do to delay the input is change the `Interactable` state of the button after is clicked by adding this line:

```
if (waterBucketAmnt < 3)
{
    waterBucketAmnt++;
    this.GetComponent<Button>().Interactable = false;
    //If Interactable is not accessible from code you could also use
    //this.gameObject.SetActive(false);
}
```

Then in the `waterBucketAction` script, you need to change the `Interactable` state of the button back to `true` once the animation is finished:

```
void FixedUpdate(}
{  
    //The 0 is the Layer Index
    if (this.animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("YourWaterAnimationName"))
        checkWaterAmnt.GetComponent<Button>().Interactable = true;
}
```

Comment: So I delayed it using StateInfo; however, I have no idea why it works. My code should be updated to what I have now. I had to use StateInfo twice for some reason. I don't get why that is, but I tried removing one and i could still detract waterAmnt by clicking the mouse 3 times while the animation played once. I feel like my program is very inefficient, but for now it doesn't matter so much. Got any ideas as to why my code works?

Comment: What do you mean by "using StateInfo twice"? Could you show the updated code? Also if this solve your problem please mark the answer as correct. Thanks.

Comment: I believe my code is updated. The only changes I made is under FixedUpdate()

Comment: I believe that the problem could be because you are using `animator.SetBool`. Intead of using a `bool` parameter in your Animator you should use a `Trigger`. When you use `animator.SetTrigger` the animation will be triggered and then the Trigger parameter will automatically change back. When you use `animator.SetBool` you need to change it back to false every loop and that could be messing with your logic. So try changing `SetBool` for `SeTrigger` and then remove one of the `GetCurrentAnimationStateInfo`.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a method to to record the number of time you pressed 'fire3' if it is less or equal to waterBucketAmnt, and then loop the waterAnim to the number for time equal to that of the recorded number. When the animation is playing it will not increment the fireCount, and it will only increment when the animation is done. Something in the line of this

```
void Update () {


    if (!animation.IsPlaying("yourWaterAnimationName"))
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire3"))
        {
            if (fireCount < waterBucketAmnt)
            {
                fireCount++;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < fireCount; i++)
    {
        animation.PlayQueued("yourWaterAnimationName");
        waterBucketAmnt--;
        fireCount--;
    }


}
```

Comment: My code is connected to an animator controller to get a blend between idle or running, so IsPlaying won't work. I might experiment with using it as an Animation later though.